# mouseenter for dynamically added content

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

I have these two events `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`:

```
$('.tltp').mouseenter(function () {
    var that = $(this)
    that.tooltip('show');
    console.log("mouseenter event fired");
    that.wait(3000).tooltip('hide');
});

$('.tltp').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

For some `input` fields that are disabled, I add the `tltp` `class` and the `TwitterBootstrap` `tooltip` dynamically to it like so:

```
// shows tooltips for disabled inputs
function AddToolTip(className) {
    d = $('.' + className);
    i = $('.' + className + ' :input');
    d.css({
        height: i.outerHeight(),
        width: i.outerWidth(),
        position: "top",
    })
    d.css(i.offset());
    d.attr("title", i.attr("data-title"));
    d.tooltip();
}
```

But for these `input` fields that are disabled and to which the `tltp` `class` gets added dynamically to it, the `mouseenter` event never gets fired.

Comment: Use `.on`: http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".tltp", function() {
var that = $(this)
that.tooltip('show');
console.log("mouseenter event fired");
that.wait(3000).tooltip('hide');
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".tltp", function() {
$(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 $('body').on('mouseenter' , '.tltp'  ,function(){
 var that = $(this)
    that.tooltip('show');
    console.log("mouseenter event fired");
    that.wait(3000).tooltip('hide');
});

 $('body').on('mouseleave' , '.tltp'  ,function(){
  $(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

you should use .on for dynamically added content

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for `dynamic elements` like,

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".tltp", function () {
    var that = $(this)
    that.tooltip('show');
    console.log("mouseenter event fired");
    that.wait(3000).tooltip('hide');
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".tltp",function () {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```